# Пытаюсь добавить SDKOptions в HERE maps

Tags: android, android-manifest

Добавляю SDKOptions в HERE maps, а библиотеку не подтягивает! Добавить в приложение данный код:

```
        SDKOptions sdkOptions = new SDKOptions("YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET", "");
```

не получается!

Вот библиотека:

```
implementation(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')
```

Comment: через строку ресурса не подходит?

Comment: Нужно чтобы код был прочитан из firebase!

Comment: Та в том то и дело ))) не могу найти! Возможно Вы подскажите. Использую HERE maps

Comment: Если бы все так просто было ))) Библиотека для этого кода не подтягивается, подозреваю, что это для премиум пакета будет работать. А пока SDKoptions can not resolve

Comment: Оно не подтягивает добавление библиотек, просит только добавить класс

Comment: Посмотрите здесь как нужно подключать локальные библиотеки: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16682847/15923106

Comment: ок! Спасибо, посмотрю обязательно